# RxScala Observable never runs

Tags: scala, rx-scala

With the following `build.sbt`:

```
name := "blah"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("io.reactivex" % "rxscala_2.11" % "0.24.1", "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "1.1.4")
```

and this code:

```
import rx.lang.scala.Observable
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Ready?")
    val o = Observable.interval(200 millis).take(5)
    o.subscribe(n => println(s"n = ${n}"))
  }

}
```

When I run it, all that's printed is `Ready?`; I see no `n = ...` at all.

I run using `sbt run`; it's built using Scala 2.6.11 and RxScala 0.24.1, as well as sbt 0.13. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your program exits before `o` fires. Try the following code:

```
import rx.lang.scala.Observable
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps
object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Ready?")
    val o = Observable.interval(200 millis).take(5)
    o.subscribe(n => println(s"n = ${n}"))

    Thread.sleep(5000)
  }

}
```

Alternatively you can replace `Thread.sleep` with `o.toBlocking.last`, which cannot return before `o` terminates.

Comment: Damn, I was going to try that! I didn't want to sleep as it's blocking etc; any "RX" way to stop it from exiting in the main func?

Comment: @atc See my edit. I think what the *correct* way is depends on your application...

Comment: Thanks, I knew `toBlocking` would work too and `last` makes sense. Will accept shortly...